# Azure Pipeline separate build directory for every branch

Tags: azure, pipeline, yocto

I have a two branches with Yocto meta data that build slightly different images (one of these images have more packages installed that helps developing code). Every branch has pipeline script.

Currently, both branches build the image in the same build directory. I want each branch to have its own build directory with its metadata, such as sstate-cache... How to achieve this?

```
trigger:
- development-image

variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: texas-image
  IMAGE_FILE: texas-image.rootfs.wic.xz  
  META_LAYERS: yocto-meta-layers
  YOCTO_RELEASE: kirkstone
  YOCTO_SOURCES: yocto-linux
  YOCTO_BUILD_DIR: build
  
  FIT_IMAGE_DIR: tools/tftp_u-boot
  FIT_IMAGE_NAME: puma

  BOOT_OVER_ETH: boot-over-eth
  IMAGE_FILE_BOOT_OVER_ETH: texas-image.rootfs.cpio.gz
  IMAGE_DEVICE_TREE_EVM_BOARD: k3-am642-evm.dtb
  IMAGE_DEVICE_TREE_SK_BOARD: k3-am642-sk.dtb
  BOOTLOADER_IMAGE_BOOT_OVER_ETH: u-boot.img
  TIBOOT3_BINARY_BOOT_OVER_ETH: tiboot3.bin
  TISPL_BINARY_BOOT_OVER_ETH: tispl.bin
  KERNEL_IMAGE_BOOT_OVER_ETH: Image
  
pool:
  #vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  name: Etteplan

stages:
 - stage: SetupYoctoEnv
   jobs:
    - job: DownloadResources
      displayName: 'Downloading resources and dependencies'
      #workspace:
      #clean: $(IMAGE_DIR)
      steps:
       - bash: |
            echo $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
            echo $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
            echo $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
            echo $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)
            
       - checkout: self # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found  clean: true
         clean: false
         path: $(YOCTO_SOURCES)

       #- task: DeleteFiles@1
       #  displayName: "Removing tmp directory"
       #  inputs:
       #     SourceFolder: $(YOCTO_BUILD_DIR)/tmp
       #     Contents: '*'
       #     RemoveSourceFolder: true

       - bash: |
            echo Creating directory structure
            ls -l
            mkdir -p ${META_LAYERS}
            mkdir -p ${BOOT_OVER_ETH}

       - bash: |
            echo Fetching Yocto meta layers
            pwd
            if [[ ! -d poky ]]; then git clone -b ${YOCTO_RELEASE} git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git; fi
            if [[ ! -d meta-openembedded ]]; then git clone -b ${YOCTO_RELEASE} git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded; fi
            if [[ ! -d meta-ti ]]; then git clone -b ${YOCTO_RELEASE} git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti; fi
            if [[ ! -d meta-arm ]]; then git clone -b ${YOCTO_RELEASE} https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-arm/; fi
         workingDirectory: $(META_LAYERS)
      
    - job: PrepareEnv
      displayName: 'Preparing Environment'
      dependsOn: 'DownloadResources'
      steps:
       - checkout: none
         clean: false
         path: $(YOCTO_SOURCES)
       - bash: |
            echo Initializing Yocto build environment
            source ${META_LAYERS}/poky/oe-init-build-env
            echo "Adding layers to bblayers.conf"
            pwd
            if ! grep -q meta-oe conf/bblayers.conf; then  bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-openembedded/meta-oe; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-python conf/bblayers.conf; then  bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-openembedded/meta-python; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-networking conf/bblayers.conf; then bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-openembedded/meta-networking; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-arm-toolchain conf/bblayers.conf; then bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-arm conf/bblayers.conf; then bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-arm/meta-arm; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-ti-bsp conf/bblayers.conf; then bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-ti/meta-ti-bsp; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-ti-extras conf/bblayers.conf; then bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/meta-ti/meta-ti-extras; fi
            if ! grep -q meta-rt conf/bblayers.conf; then bitbake-layers add-layer ../${META_LAYERS}/../meta-rt; fi
         
 - stage: BuildImage
   dependsOn: 
    - SetupYoctoEnv
   jobs:
    - job: BuildImage
      displayName: 'Building Yocto image'
      timeoutInMinutes: 300
      steps:
       - checkout: none
         clean: false
         path: $(YOCTO_SOURCES)
       - bash: |  
           source ${META_LAYERS}/poky/oe-init-build-env
           bitbake ${IMAGE_NAME}

    - job: BuildFitImage
      displayName: 'Building Fit Image'
      dependsOn: 'BuildImage'
      steps:
       - checkout: none
         clean: false
         path: $(YOCTO_SOURCES)

       - bash: |
            ln -s ../../$(YOCTO_BUILD_DIR)/tmp/deploy/images/am64xx-evm bin
            ls -l bin
            mkimage -f ${FIT_IMAGE_NAME}.its ${FIT_IMAGE_NAME}.itb
         workingDirectory: $(FIT_IMAGE_DIR)


 - stage: Publish
   dependsOn: 
    - BuildImage
   jobs:
     - job: PublishImage
       displayName: 'Publish Image'
       steps:
        - checkout: none

        - task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: 'Collecting files boot over ethernet'
          inputs:
             sourceFolder: '$(YOCTO_BUILD_DIR)/tmp/deploy/images/am64xx-evm'
             contents: |
                  $(IMAGE_FILE_BOOT_OVER_ETH)
                  $(IMAGE_DEVICE_TREE_EVM_BOARD)
                  $(IMAGE_DEVICE_TREE_SK_BOARD)
                  $(BOOTLOADER_IMAGE_BOOT_OVER_ETH)
                  $(TIBOOT3_BINARY_BOOT_OVER_ETH)
                  $(TIBOOT3_BINARY_BOOT_OVER_ETH)
                  $(TISPL_BINARY_BOOT_OVER_ETH)
                  $(KERNEL_IMAGE_BOOT_OVER_ETH)
             overWrite: true
             targetFolder: '$(BOOT_OVER_ETH)'
          
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
             rootFolderOrFile: $(BOOT_OVER_ETH)
             archiveType: 'zip'
             archiveFile: $(BOOT_OVER_ETH).zip
             replaceExistingArchive: true
             verbose: true
              
        
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
             targetPath: $(BOOT_OVER_ETH).zip
             artifactType: 'pipeline'
             artifactName: $(BOOT_OVER_ETH)

        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
             targetPath: $(YOCTO_BUILD_DIR)/tmp/deploy/images/am64xx-evm/$(IMAGE_FILE)
             artifactType: 'pipeline'
             artifactName: $(IMAGE_NAME)

        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
             targetPath: $(FIT_IMAGE_DIR)/$(FIT_IMAGE_NAME).itb
             artifactType: 'pipeline'
             artifactName: fit-image-$(FIT_IMAGE_NAME)
```

Thanks for help:)

Comment: Can you share the pipeline script or code that executes the build ?

Comment: Yes, I posted the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All builds will happen in the same `build` folder, because you did not pass build name to `source ${META_LAYERS}/poky/oe-init-build-env` in the `BuildImage` job.

So, each time you run the pipeline, the `oe-init-build-env` will source the same build.

You can create new variable to get the branch name automatically and then:

```
variables:
  BRANCH_NAME: example

..
    - job: BuildImage
      displayName: 'Building Yocto image'
      timeoutInMinutes: 300
      steps:
       - checkout: none
         clean: false
         path: $(YOCTO_SOURCES)
       - bash: |  
           source ${META_LAYERS}/poky/oe-init-build-env -b $(BRANCH_NAME)
                                                        ^
                                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------/
```